# Select input tag by Nokogiri rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have some troubles finding the way to select and show the info of a page, I'm using NOKOGIRI and Rails 3.

So I would like to select the follow input tag:

```
<input type="text" name="tarificador.codPosDest.desMuniEstado" size="60"      value="PUEBLA,PUEBLA              " readonly="readonly" style="font-size: 11px;
                                            font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                                            color: #575553;
                                            font-weight: bold;
                                            text-align: justify;
                                            background-color: #f6ecce;
                                            border:0;">
```

I need the value of this input tag, how can I show it in a view, I'm using something like this at my controller:

```
tarifa = ""
 doc.css("#tarificador.codPosDest.desMuniEstado").each do |d|
   puts d.attr("value")
   puts d.text
   tarifa << d.text
 end

respond_to do |format|
  if @sender.save
    format.html do 
        redirect_to @sender, notice: 'Sender was successfully created.'
        flash[:tarifa] = tarifa
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my view, I just show the flash tag:

```
  <div class="estafeta">
   <%=h flash[:tarifa].html_safe %>
  </div>
```

Do you know a better way to show the data?

PS: the code that I have at input doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting by it's name attribute, not id so maybe:

```
tarifa = doc.search('input[name="tarificador.codPosDest.desMuniEstado"]').map{|x| x[:value]} * '<br />'
```

The `text` would always be empty.